# How to ignore the sender parameter UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, sender

I was using a function as an `@IBAction` but now I want to use it as a normal function. But the problem is when I try to call the function it is asking me for the sender and is expecting a `UIButton` as a parameter.
How can I remove that sender so it doesn't affect my function?

Here is my function:

```
func addProductToCartButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // Start animation region
    let buttonPosition : CGPoint = sender.convert(sender.bounds.origin, to: self.productsTableView)

    let indexPath = self.productsTableView.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)!

    let cell = productsTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! ProductTableViewCell

    let imageViewPosition : CGPoint = cell.productImageView.convert(cell.productImageView.bounds.origin, to: self.view)

    let imgViewTemp = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: imageViewPosition.x, y: imageViewPosition.y, width: cell.productImageView.frame.size.width, height: cell.productImageView.frame.size.height))

    imgViewTemp.image = cell.productImageView.image

    animationProduct(tempView: imgViewTemp)

    // End animation region
}
```

Here is where I need to call the function:

```
func didTapAddToCart(_ cell: ProductTableViewCell) {
    let indexPath = self.productsTableView.indexPath(for: cell)
        addProductToCartButton( expecting UIBUTTON parameter)
    }
```

I was trying to set the sender as `nil` but is not working. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to refactor your code. The current implementation of `addProductToCartButton` uses the sender (the button) to determine an index path. And then the rest of the code is based on that index path.

You then have your `didTapAddToCart` method which attempts to call `addProductToCartButton` but you don't have the button at this point but it does have an index path.

I would create a new function that takes an index path as its parameter. Its implementation is most of the existing code in `addProductToCartButton`.

Here's the new function (which is mostly the original `addProductToCartButton` code):

```
func addProduct(at indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = productsTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! ProductTableViewCell

    let imageViewPosition : CGPoint = cell.productImageView.convert(cell.productImageView.bounds.origin, to: self.view)

    let imgViewTemp = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: imageViewPosition.x, y: imageViewPosition.y, width: cell.productImageView.frame.size.width, height: cell.productImageView.frame.size.height))

    imgViewTemp.image = cell.productImageView.image

    animationProduct(tempView: imgViewTemp)

    // End animation region
}
```

Then redo `addProductToCartButton` as:

```
func addProductToCartButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // Start animation region
    let buttonPosition : CGPoint = sender.convert(sender.bounds.origin, to: self.productsTableView)

    let indexPath = self.productsTableView.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)!

    addProduct(at: indexPath)
}
```

And finally, update `didTapAddToCart`:

```
func didTapAddToCart(_ cell: ProductTableViewCell) {
    let indexPath = self.productsTableView.indexPath(for: cell)
    addProduct(at: indexPath)
}
```

Comment: Rmaddy you are a genius ! Is working perfect and I didn't lost my animation. I was thinking to remove it because I didn't know how to fix the problem with the sender. Thank you from my deep soul ! You made me so happy !

Answer (score 3):

#### Approach 1 (Recommended):

You can make that argument as optional:

```
@IBAction func addProductToCartButton(_ sender: UIButton?)
{
   // Do your stuff here
}
```

Now you can call it like:

```
addProductToCartButton(nil)
```

---

#### Approach 2 (Not Recommended)

If you don't want to make the argument as optional, you can call it like:

```
addProductToCartButton(UIButton()) // It's not recommended
```

---

#### Approach 3 (Recommended)

Just write another utility function and add the code in it (Add the code written inside the IBAction to this function). Instead of calling `IBAction` from another function, call this utility function.

Comment: Approach 1 is ok but is crushing because the sender is NIL. And I don't want to hardcode the X and Y for that buttonPosition. Any idea how can I fix it ? Thanks.

Comment: How do you expect to get the button position (the first line of your method) without passing in the button or without hardcoding the values? You need to rework your method so it doesn't depend on the sender parameter.

Comment: This answer can't work since the a non-nil sender is required by the code inside the action method.

Comment: @rmaddy can you tell me please how do you think I should do it without to affect my `sender` or how I can refactor my function to replace the `sender` with something else ? Thank you for your time !

Answer (score 1):

Extending `Midhun MP`s answer you can make your function call even simpler by providing a default value of `nil`:

```
@IBAction func addProductToCartButton(_ sender: UIButton? = nil) {
   // Do your stuff here
}
```

Then you can call the function like this:

```
addProductToCartButton()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well simplest approach for this type of logic is, pass **nil value** as **parameter**, it would be like this,

```
addProductToCartButton(nil)
```

Just make sure that you are not using any button property in your function. But if you are using button property then just simple add a check in your function like this,

```
func addProductToCartButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if sender != nil {
        //Do Something
    }
}
```

Hope this will solve your issue, Thanks for reading this.